# Индексация счетчиков

Tags: seo

Здравствуйте, у меня на сайте есть несколько счетчиков: рамблер, лайвинтернет и т.д.
И естественно каждый счетчик ведет ссылку на свою страницу, влияет ли это как-нибудь на индексацию? Может нужно обвернуть их в тег `<noindex>`?

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток. На индексацию — никак. На ранжирование: именно наличие счетчиков — скорее никак, но их присутствие на странице дает поисковикам возможность анализировать поведение пользователя и вводить в формулу ранжирования поведенчиские факторы, а это как минимум:

- количество отказов;
- глубина просмотров;
- время пребывания на сайте.

**Вывод**: Для нормального сайта наличие счетчиков — это хорошо и оборачивать их не надо. Если же сайт не для людей, а для раскрутки то счетчики лучше вообще убрать, т.к. даже обернутые в `<noindex>` они продолжают работать.